# Python unresolved import win32clipboard

Tags: python

I just tried to use the following code:

```
data = win32clipboard.GetClipBoardData(win32clipboard.CF_TEXT)
```

Error is

```
Error = module 'win32clipboard' has no attribute 'GetClipBoardData'
```

when I try to import win32clipboard it says unresolved import. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it for Windows? maybe is not correctly installed

Comment: Please check with: >>> help('win32clipboard')

Comment: Just used tkinter. Solved my problem so I dont need this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled `GetClipBoardData()` - should have been `GetClipboardData()`

Importing the `win32.win32clipboard` solves the intellisense issues:

```py
import win32.win32clipboard as clip
clip.OpenClipboard()
data = clip.GetClipboardData(clip.CF_TEXT)
clip.CloseClipboard()
print(data)
```